# Issues with jquery post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a simple hello world app to test connecting front end and back end. The back end is a simple flask app.

This is the JS that executes on button click:

```js
function mouseAction() {
    let helloWorldButton = document.getElementById('btn')
    helloWorldButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        //post request goes here
        console.log("mouse clicked!")
        $.post({
            url: "http://localhost:5000/hello_world",
            data: {},
            success: function(data){
                formatReturnedData(data)
            },
            dataType: 'string'
        })
        console.log(data)
        console.log('hi bruh')
    })
}
```

I know the request is received by the server because my daemon logs it:

[image: network log]

But the 'hi bruh' or the 'data' never get printed to console, what am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Two questions for you... 1) What triggers your `mouseAction` function? 2) What sort of element is `helloWorldButton` and what attributes does it have?

Comment: do console.log in success handler, and check

Comment: @Phil, first, thanks for adding the image :). The mouseAction is triggered by a user click. helloWorldButton is just a simple button: ```<button id="btn" type="button" >Get A Hello World!</button>```.

Comment: @NilayTiwari I put that in, but nothing gets printed to console, even just a regular console.log('hi') doesn't get printed to console, I guess the success function never actually gets called.

Comment: No problem and thanks for replying. You don't want to be registering a click handler in another click handler. That will add duplicate event handler every time the user clicks.

Comment: @Phil what's the alternative then? Adding an ```onclick=``` to the button tag itself?

Comment: No, just add the click handler. The only thing you need to wait for is the element to exist in the document. Eg `jQuery(function($) { $('#btn').on('click', function() { /* do ajax stuff */ }) })`

Comment: @Phil worked like a charm, still not really sure why this is preferred, but the help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request is not formed properly. Your `console.log`s should be inside of your success callback function. And `'string'` is not a valid `dataType` value.

Try this instead:

```
$.post({
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/hello_world',
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {
    formatReturnedData(data);
    console.log(data);
    console.log('hi bruh');
  },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

For more details see the docs https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Actually shorthand methods now take options objects the same as `$.ajax` See the `jQuery.post( [settings ] )`  definitions section

Comment: You're right @charlietfl, I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Data only exists inside the success function

```
function mouseAction() {
    let helloWorldButton = document.getElementById('btn')
    helloWorldButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        //post request goes here
        console.log("mouse clicked!")
        $.post({
            url: "http://localhost:5000/hello_world",
            data: {},
            success: function(data){
                formatReturnedData(data)
                console.log(data)
                console.log('hi bruh')
            },
            dataType: 'string'
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default jquery ajax request works asynchronously. In that case as you putted your console.log after the server request console.log is executing before server response. If you put console.log inside success call back function the problem will resolve. For example

```js
function mouseAction() {
    let helloWorldButton = document.getElementById('btn')
    helloWorldButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        //post request goes here
        console.log("mouse clicked!")
        $.post({
            url: "http://localhost:5000/hello_world",
            data: {},
            success: function(data){
                formatReturnedData(data)
                console.log(data)
                console.log('hi bruh')
            },
            dataType: 'string'
        })
    })
}
```